# ETL & Parsing CSV files in Cloud Dataflow

Tags: csv, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm new to cloud dataflow and Java so I'm hoping this is the right question to ask.

I have a csv file with n number of columns and rows that could be a string, integer or timestamp. Do I need to create a new PCollection for each column?

Most of the documentation that I've found in examples is along the lines of something like:

```
PCollection<String> data = p.apply(TextIO.Read.from("gs://abc/def.csv"));
```

But to me it doesn't make sense to import an entire csv file as a string. What am I missing here and how should I set my PCollections up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example will create a collection containing 1 `String` per line in the file, e.g. if the file is:

```
Alex,28,111-222-3344
Sam,30,555-666-7788
Drew,19,123-45-6789
```

then the collection will logically contain `"Alex,28,111-222-3344"`, `"Sam,30,555-666-7788"`, and `"Drew,19,123-45-6789"`. You can apply further parsing code in Java by piping the collection through a `ParDo` or `MapElements` transform, e.g.:

```
class User {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public String phone;
}

PCollection<String> lines = p.apply(TextIO.Read.from("gs://abc/def.csv"));
PCollection<User> users = lines.apply(MapElements.via((String line) -> {
    User user = new User();
    String[] parts = line.split(",");
    user.name = parts[0];
    user.age = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    user.phone = parts[2];
    return user;
}).withOutputType(new TypeDescriptor<User>() {});)
```

Comment: Thank you @jkff, I'll take a look at that now.

Comment: I'd split using String[] parts = line.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)") to account for extra commas and quotes.

Comment: This is great, thanks. Is there a more robust way to handle CSVs with unexpected column order?

Comment: @Eugene in your example is it possible to use
`lines.apply(ParDo.of(new CreateUser())`
and writing conversion logic in DoFn processElement method? and what is the use of withOutputType().

Comment: ParDo would work too, it's just less concise. withOutputType is needed for technical reasons related to Java type Erasure, coder inference will not work in this case if you omit it.

Answer (score 5):

```
line.split(",");
```

String.split doesn't make sense if the line data like this:

> a,b,c,"we,have a string contains comma",d,e

A property way to deal with the csv data is to import a csv library:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

and use codes below inside ParDo:

```
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws IOException {
    String line = c.element();
    CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser();
    String[] parts = csvParser.parseLine(line);
}
```