# Reading Excel file in Google Cloud Dataflow from file stored in GCS

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, apache-poi, google-cloud-dataflow

Currently Google Cloud Dataflow does not support reading Excel file from Google Cloud Storage.

For the work around, I tried below things,

I was trying to use app engine tools to read the Excel file and then used Apache POI and was trying to convert Excel file to CSV file.

Below is the code sample used,

`GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
GcsFilename fileName = new GcsFilename("TestBucket", "Test1.xlsx"); 
GcsInputChannel readChannel = gcsService.openPrefetchingReadChannel(fileName, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
InputStream inputStream = Channels.newInputStream(readChannel);`

And then added Apache POI to read InputStream

`XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);`

But received below error,

```
Aug 17, 2017 6:58:35 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl waitForFetch
WARNING: PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl [filename=GcsFilename(TestBucket, Test1.xlsx), blockSizeBytes=2048, closed=false, eofHit=false, length=-1, fetchPosition=0, pendingFetch=com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ImmediateFailedFuture@7770f470, retryParams=RetryParams [requestTimeoutMillis=30000, requestTimeoutRetryFactor=1.2, maxRequestTimeout=60000, retryMinAttempts=3, retryMaxAttempts=6, initialRetryDelayMillis=1000, maxRetryDelayMillis=32000, retryDelayBackoffFactor=2.0, totalRetryPeriodMillis=50000]]: IOException fetching block
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ImmediateFailedFuture.get(Futures.java:234)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.waitForFetch(PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.access$000(PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.java:43)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl$1.call(PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.java:136)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl$1.call(PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.java:134)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:108)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:166)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:156)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.waitForFetchWithRetry(PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.java:134)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.read(PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.java:212)
at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readLOC(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:83)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:267)
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:204)
at chalel.paratChalel.main(paratChalel.java:102)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService$BlobStorageAdapter.getInstance(LocalRawGcsService.java:186)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService$BlobStorageAdapter.access$000(LocalRawGcsService.java:109)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService.ensureInitialized(LocalRawGcsService.java:194)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService.readObjectAsync(LocalRawGcsService.java:432)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.requestBlock(PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.java:107)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.<init>(PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.java:88)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl.openPrefetchingReadChannel(GcsServiceImpl.java:126)
at chalel.paratChalel.main(paratChalel.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService$BlobStorageAdapter.<init>(LocalRawGcsService.java:123)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService$BlobStorageAdapter.getInstance(LocalRawGcsService.java:184)
... 7 more

Aug 17, 2017 6:58:35 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry
INFO: RetryHelper(44.11 ms, 1 attempts, com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl$1@7bedc48a): Attempt #1 failed [java.io.IOException: PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl [filename=GcsFilename(TestBucket, Test1.xlsx), blockSizeBytes=2048, closed=false, eofHit=false, length=-1, fetchPosition=0, pendingFetch=com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ImmediateFailedFuture@77f1baf5, retryParams=RetryParams [requestTimeoutMillis=30000, requestTimeoutRetryFactor=1.2, maxRequestTimeout=60000, retryMinAttempts=3, retryMaxAttempts=6, initialRetryDelayMillis=1000, maxRetryDelayMillis=32000, retryDelayBackoffFactor=2.0, totalRetryPeriodMillis=50000]]: Prefetch failed, prefetching again], sleeping for 1146 ms
Aug 17, 2017 6:58:36 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl waitForFetch
WARNING: PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl [filename=GcsFilename(TestBucket, Test1.xlsx), blockSizeBytes=2048, closed=false, eofHit=false, length=-1, fetchPosition=0, pendingFetch=com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ImmediateFailedFuture@77f1baf5, retryParams=RetryParams [requestTimeoutMillis=30000, requestTimeoutRetryFactor=1.2, maxRequestTimeout=60000, retryMinAttempts=3, retryMaxAttempts=6, initialRetryDelayMillis=1000, maxRetryDelayMillis=32000, retryDelayBackoffFactor=2.0, totalRetryPeriodMillis=50000]]: IOException fetching block
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ImmediateFailedFuture.get(Futures.java:234)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.waitForFetch(PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.access$000(PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.java:43)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl$1.call(PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.java:136)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl$1.call(PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.java:134)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:108)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:166)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:156)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.waitForFetchWithRetry(PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.java:134)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.read(PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.java:212)
at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readLOC(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:83)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:267)
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:204)
at chalel.paratChalel.main(paratChalel.java:102)
```

Note: I have added below dependencies in pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
<version>3.9</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine.tools/appengine-gcs-client -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
<artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
<version>0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

What can be the issue?

Comment: How complex is the excel sheet? Is it simple values or does it contain formulas?

Comment: For now, we are considering the simple one. Aim is to be able to read excel atleast.

Comment: Reading excel file stored in GCS using Dataflow is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43640943/8213464 which can answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

This code converts all sheets in Excel as CSV's with same Sheet Name. Through ReadChannel link Excel file stored in google cloud to FileInputStream Java. From there use Excel readable libraries (POI in this case) to connect to file inputstream. For loop converts Excel sheet to CSV. Declare a BlobId and through write channel write it to Google cloud bucket.

```
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 64 * 1024;

private static void printBlob(com.google.cloud.storage.Storage storage, String bucketName, String blobPath)
        throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
    try (ReadChannel reader = ((com.google.cloud.storage.Storage) storage).reader(bucketName, blobPath)) {
        InputStream inputStream = Channels.newInputStream(reader);
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
        StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            String fName = wb.getSheetAt(i).getSheetName();
            XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) wb.getSheetAt(i);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            data.delete(0, data.length());
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                // Get Each Row
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                data.append('\n');
                // Iterating through Each column of Each Row
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    // Checking the cell format
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        data.append(cell.getNumericCellValue() + ",");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        data.append(cell.getStringCellValue() + ",");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        data.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + ",");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                        data.append("" + ",");
                        break;
                    default:
                        data.append(cell + ",");
                    }
                }

            }
            String filename = "test_excel/"+fName;
            BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketname, filename);
             byte[] content = data.toString().getBytes(UTF_8);
            BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build();
            try (WriteChannel writer = storage.writer(blobInfo)) {
                writer.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(content, 0, content.length));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please write an explanation of why this code is a good answer to the question, as not all readers would understand that. Code only answer are not always very helpful. use the [edit] button to improve your answer please.

Comment: This code converts all sheets in Excel as CSV's with same Sheet Name. Through ReadChannel link excel file stored in google cloud to FileInputStream java. From there use excel readable libraries(POI in this case) to connect to file inputstream. for loop converts excel sheet to csv. Declare a BlobId and through write channel write it to google cloud bucket

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered trying [Cloud Dataprep](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/) for reading your Excel data?

It natively supports [Excel workbooks](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Import-Excel-Data_57344579), though they need to be uploaded to Dataprep, versus being read from GCS. If you are trying to parse and clean Excel workbook data for further analysis, Dataprep may be more convenient, and it happens to use Dataflow for processing underneath.