# How read XLS file from gcp bucket

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I have on bucket `XLS` file and I have to pull the file and read the data on the stream and work with data. I worked with `CSV` file and this is my code:

```
try (ReadChannel reader = storage.reader(bucketName, fileName)) {   
            ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE);
            while (reader.read(bytes) > 0) {
                bytes.flip();
                // outChannel.write(bytes);
                set(new String(bytes.array(), "UTF-8"), fileName); 
                bytes.clear();
            }
        }
```

Comment: steps to get xls file from cloud storage should remain the same as getting csv file. What issue are you facing when you tried fetching xls file?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for. [GCS Input Channel](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/googlecloudstorageclient/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/cloudstorage/GcsInputChannel)

```
GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
GcsFilename fileName = new GcsFilename("TestBucket", "Test1.xlsx"); 
GcsInputChannel readChannel = gcsService.openPrefetchingReadChannel(fileName, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
InputStream inputStream = Channels.newInputStream(readChannel);
```

I've also found an interesting workaround that might help you, in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51260194/11928097) you have a piece of code that converts all the excel files to CSV to let you manipulate them as normal if you wish to.

EDIT: The error was there because it was not initialized. Have a look at my code edit.

In your case as far as I understood you might need to use "[OutputChannel](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/googlecloudstorageclient/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/cloudstorage/GcsOutputChannel)" not "InputChannel" but it's the same concept.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Could you explain me the  `gcsService.openPrefetchingReadChannel(fileName, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);` what is this.

Comment: Here you have a better explanation of what openPrefetchingReadChannel https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/googlecloudstorageclient/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/cloudstorage/GcsService#openPrefetchingReadChannel-com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsFilename-long-int- does.

Comment: When I copy the `gcsService.openPrefetchingReadChannel(fileName, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);` I have the error : `gcsService cannot be resolved`.

Comment: I have the error : `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException`
When add inputStream into :
`XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
  XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  Row row = sheet.getRow(1);`

Comment: The issue is clearly in something that you are trying to retrieve and not pointing correctly to. I'm not sure exactly where the issue can be. I imagine you're not reaching the sheet correctly. 

Another thing that you can try is directly downloading from the bucket the XLS and then reading it and manipulating the data/stream. Try that.